# Huawei IAP When select Chinese mainland : MAJOR:22: Integrate the version update API (checkUpdate)

Tags: android, kotlin, in-app-purchase, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-iap

I have an error when select Chinese mainland:

MAJOR:22: Integrate the version update API (checkUpdate). If you already integrate the API, check whether the HMS SDK code is obfuscated in the configuration file. For details about how to modify the configuration file, visit https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/appgallerykit-preparation#h1-1574846682104 ;SUGGESTION:17: HMS SDK APIs that are called: 34: Integrated HMS services: [agconnect-core, iap, base]

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

（1）MAJOR:22:——For this，you can integrate the version update API (checkUpdate), referring to following link.

- [Game application](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/appgallerykit-game-update?ha_source=hms1)
- [Common application](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/appgallerykit-app-update?ha_source=hms1)

（2）SUGGESTION:17、30 and 34,——you can ignore it, Manual approval prevails.

Comment: HI, I m using cordova ionic, android studio 4.1, gradle 1.10.3 and already follow all step in the documentation, does it because the obfuscated issue that in the error: If you already integrate the API, check whether the HMS SDK code is obfuscated in the configuration file?

Comment: you can refer this [link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides-V1/config-obfuscation-0000001062476976-V1) to configuration obfuscation :)

Comment: My app has been rejected and never approved yet and still I had to do the above procedure because of I am targeting Chinese mainland. This is weird

Answer (score 0):

The documentation has changed: [Updating an App](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/AppGallery-connect-Guides/appgallerykit-app-update-0000001055118286) & [ProGuard](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/appgallerykit-getting-started-0000001055756858#section1448912915419).

This would be the dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.huawei.hms:base:6.12.0.301"
    implementation "com.huawei.hms:hmscoreinstaller:6.12.0.301"
    implementation "com.huawei.hms:appservice:6.12.0.300"
}
```

Which provide the classes used in the documentation:

```
import com.huawei.hms.jos.AppParams;
import com.huawei.hms.jos.AppUpdateClient;
import com.huawei.hms.jos.JosApps;
import com.huawei.hms.jos.JosAppsClient;

import com.huawei.updatesdk.service.appmgr.bean.ApkUpgradeInfo;
import com.huawei.updatesdk.service.otaupdate.CheckUpdateCallBack;
import com.huawei.updatesdk.service.otaupdate.UpdateKey;
```

---

Beside the technical aspect, an [ICP filing](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/cn/doc/quickApp-Guides/quickapp-icp-system-first-0000001773327886) is required by law, which ultimately depends on the [Unified Social Credit Identifier](https://bt.gsxt.gov.cn/index.html). Unless having a Chinese company, there doesn't seem to be a way. When not distributing the app to "Mainland China", it may not be rejected without review.