# App rejecting on AppGallery Connect Huawei

Tags: huawei-developers, appgallery-connect

My app is getting rejected with the below-mentioned comment but I am unable to understand what actually needs to be done to resolve this step. If anyone has uploaded the app on AppGallery Connect, kindly help me understand why my app is not getting accepted.

Review comments:
App review results：

1.Your App failed to pass the App recordal verification.

[Suggestion]: Please complete the App recordal verification as soon as possible.

For details about App recordal verification, please refer to: https://www.miit.gov.cn/zwgk/zcjd/art/2023/art_39b4f1acc36745b98478e0ec3e07128d.html

Comment: I've generally [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78216076/549372) this before already.